# Pandas - Date ranges that doesn't overlap

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting lost in trying to find a easy way to determine when date ranges from 2 data frame are not overlapping.

I have 2 dataframes :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'START':['2019-01-01 09:00:00', '2019-01-01 18:00:00'],
    'END':['2019-01-01 16:00:00', '2019-01-02 02:00:00']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'START':['2019-01-01 08:00:00', '2019-01-01 14:00:00', '2019-01-01 22:00:00', '2019-01-02 01:00:00'],
    'END':['2019-01-01 11:00:00', '2019-01-01 15:00:00', '2019-01-01 23:00:00', '2019-01-02 04:00:00']})

df1 :
                 START                  END
0  2019-01-01 09:00:00  2019-01-01 16:00:00
1  2019-01-01 18:00:00  2019-01-02 02:00:00

df2 :
                 START                  END
0  2019-01-01 08:00:00  2019-01-01 11:00:00
1  2019-01-01 14:00:00  2019-01-01 15:00:00
2  2019-01-01 22:00:00  2019-01-01 23:00:00
3  2019-01-02 01:00:00  2019-01-02 04:00:00
```

and I would like get the date range when df1 is not overlapped by df2:

```
                 START                  END
0  2019-01-01 11:00:00  2019-01-01 14:00:00
1  2019-01-01 15:00:00  2019-01-01 16:00:00
2  2019-01-01 18:00:00  2019-01-01 22:00:00
3  2019-01-01 23:00:00  2019-01-02 01:00:00
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I understand your question, but what is the logic behind the calculation? I see that rows shift up and down.

Comment: Last row of output does not look correct to me. Should be from 23:00 to 1:00?

Comment: @QuangHoang. You're right I did mistakes in the df of results. It should be more understandable now. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sympy` and it's `Interval` could be used, here's an example

```
from sympy import Interval
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def remove_overlap(time_intervals, overlapping_intervals):
    time_span = None

    for _, interval in time_intervals.iterrows():
        start_ts = parser.parse(interval["START"]).timestamp()
        end_ts = parser.parse(interval["END"]).timestamp()
        interval_ts = Interval(start_ts, end_ts)
        time_span = interval_ts + time_span if time_span else interval_ts

    for _, interval in overlapping_intervals.iterrows():
        start_ts = parser.parse(interval["START"]).timestamp()
        end_ts = parser.parse(interval["END"]).timestamp()
        interval_ts = Interval(start_ts, end_ts)
        time_span = time_span - interval_ts

    bounds_ts = list(time_span.boundary)
    bounds_dates = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in bounds_ts]

    df = pd.DataFrame({"START": bounds_dates[0::2], "END":bounds_dates[1::2]})
    return df

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'START':['2019-01-01 09:00:00', '2019-01-01 18:00:00'],
    'END':['2019-01-01 16:00:00', '2019-01-02 02:00:00']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'START':['2019-01-01 08:00:00', '2019-01-01 14:00:00', '2019-01-01 22:00:00', '2019-01-02 01:00:00'],
    'END':['2019-01-01 11:00:00', '2019-01-01 15:00:00', '2019-01-01 23:00:00', '2019-01-02 04:00:00']})

remove_overlap(df1,df2)
```

this outputs

```
START   END
0   2019-01-01 11:00:00 2019-01-01 14:00:00
1   2019-01-01 15:00:00 2019-01-01 16:00:00
2   2019-01-01 18:00:00 2019-01-01 22:00:00
3   2019-01-01 23:00:00 2019-01-02 01:00:00
```

Comment: you'll need to install `sympy` - it's not in a standard library. Use `pip` as `pip install sympy` or `pip install --user sympy` if you're not an admin on that machine.

Comment: Thanks @avloss. I could adapt your code with mine and everything work fine.